# Trick to get appropriate auto complete method in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a query what is the best trick to easily get correct method using autocomplete in Xcode for swift.

Like for objective C the trick is use - sign for instance method and + for class methods.

Then next just add return type Xcode will show you appropriate methods.

For example if I want to get the the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of tableview datasource.
I have attached two images how result changes when we provide return type.

1. Without adding return type

[image]

2. With return type.
   [image]

Now since in swift syntax of a function or method return type is at the end of the function, what else we can do to easily get required results.

Comment: you just start typing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will get that particular method.

Comment: have you tried so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just start typing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will get that particular method. No need to type from `tableView`...blah blah... Just type the methods **main phrase**, then you will get correct method in suggestion.

[image]

Thanks:)